# Accessing google cloud storage with c++

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Is there a way to 'get' and 'post' data to a google cloud bucket from a c++ application(which is hosted on the container engine)? There are no client libraries for c++ listed on the official documentation here

Comment: Yes, there very likely is a way to do it. What is your actual question?

Comment: @n0rd I want to get file by name and post data to google bucket using c++.